# Wait for user input from modal box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the user's answer from a modal popup box that launches to confirm if the user is certain on what he is doing.

[image: modal popup box]

I am using ReactJs so I will give some context so everyone can understand how this part of the project is structured. The modal is a component that I am planning to use in other components. I am using the useRef hook to get the modal reference in the parent component. The modal component's functions look like this :

```
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [disabledInputs, setDisabledInputs] = useState({ confirm: false });
  const [confirmation, setConfirmation] = useState(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      openModal: () => open(),
      closeModal: () => close(),
      getAnswer: () => getAnswer(),
    };
  });

  const close = async () => {
    setConfirmation(false);
    setDisplay(false);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setConfirmation(null);
    }, 500);
  };

  const open = () => {
    setDisplay(true);
  };

  const getAnswer = () => {
    return confirmation;
  };

  const confirm = () => {
    setConfirmation(true);
    setDisplay(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setConfirmation(null);
    }, 500);
  };
```

In the parent component I got a button that calls the following function whenever its clicked.

```
const assingOrder = async () => {
    setDisabledInputs((prevDisabledInputs) => {
      return { ...prevDisabledInputs, assignProv: true };
    });

    const id = await getProviderIDWithEmail(inputs.provider);
    if (id !== null) {
      modalRef.current.openModal();
      let answer = modalRef.current.getAnswer();
      const i = setInterval(() => {
        answer = modalRef.current.getAnswer();
        console.log(answer);
        if (answer !== null) {
          clearInterval(i);
          setDisabledInputs((prevDisabledInputs) => {
            return { ...prevDisabledInputs, assignProv: false };
          });
        }
      }, 500);
    } else {
      setDisabledInputs((prevDisabledInputs) => {
        return { ...prevDisabledInputs, assignProv: false };
      });
    }
  };
```

This code actually works but it seems messy and I think there may be some better way to approach this using a listener or something like that, so I was hoping someone could help me out with this. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to have a setInterval there to check on whether an answer is given. Better to use an onChange or onClick event handler for that. You can have a variable in state, say, `disableInputs` that gets set to true when the modal opens and is set to false when the reply event happens, and you can set you input disabled states based on that. It looks like your modal has a screen overlay behind it too, which is good for blocking user input.

Comment: The problem here is that the modal may be open but the user may have not answered yet, the user in some weird case may take up to 1 minute to answer.. I thought of a way to make getAnswer asynchronous and return the value when the user clicks the confirmation button or clicks the close button, but didn't know how to implement it

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the issue, but it seems to me this is exactly what event listeners are good at, waiting for an event, however long it may take, and then doing some action in response to that event. If the modal opens and there's an onClick handler on the button, it could sit for a minute or an hour or whatever and it will still be ready to handle the click event whenever that occurs. No need for you to keep checking in on it with an interval.

Comment: Sure! You are right... with your last comment I began to rethink my approach and will update my question with a possible solution to this matter. Thank you!